# How to force click and select-all feature to be case sensitive in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-code

In my installation of Visual Studio Code on Windows, when I click on a word, all occurrences of that word will be high lighted, regardless of their case!

As you see in this picture the click and select all feature of the visual studio is case-insensitive by default!

How can I make it case-sensitive so that it only highlights case-sensitive? e.g. to highlight only "case", not "CASE" or "caSe" when we click on "case"

[image]

Comment: Are you doing a Find?  Or a replace?  Or are you just clicking on the word `case` in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `Match Case` button in the Find dialog.

You can toggle this with `Alt+C`.